# Getting the value from 1st AJAX call gives Undefined

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

**UPDATE:**
Solved it! inside AJAX Call, I've added `var str2 = document.getElementById("bfnsCode").value;` where **bfnsCode** is the **id** of drop down list.

```
function showTaxtype(str) {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
        return;
    }
    var url = "/BIR-MRCOSv1.2/servlet-test2.jsp";
    url += "?bfns=" + str;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = taxtypeChange;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function showAcctcode(str) {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined ") {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
        return;
    }
    var str2 = document.getElementById("bfnsCode").value;

        var url = "/BIR-MRCOSv1.2/servlet-test3.jsp";
        url += "?taxt=" + str + "&bfns=" + str2;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = acctcodeChange;
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

I want to get the value of **bfns** from 1st ajax call and use it again to the 2nd ajax. In this code I declared a value(str2) that supposed to have the value of **bfns** and add that variable to 2nd ajax because my 3 drop down list requires two values, but the variable I declare gives me an **undefined** value.

Comment: Perform the second ajax request inside the `taxtypeChange` callback.

Comment: I can not see any code that assigns the response of the first call to the local variable bfns.

Comment: I thought a simple declaration of variable calls the value of bfns from **showTaxtype** function.

Comment: All I want is to have the value of **str2** same as bfns. I don't know how to call it.

Comment: if you've solved it, add it as an answer and mark that one accepted.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, how should do it? I've tick the star and I can't vote up yet.